Oracle group in rows
I have a table that I would like to group by row. With "group by" the entire column is always grouped.
Source-Table



ID
HBS1




1
MU


1
S


1
S


1
S


1
T


1
T


1
SZ


1
S


1
S


1
S




Wish-Table



ID
HBS1
COUNT




1
MU
1


1
S
3


1
T
2


1
SZ
1


1
S
3



I hope you can help me a little. Thanks.

Keep in mind that Values stored on the table are not sorted. You must have a column which uniquely identifies every row and can be used as a sorting clause

In SQL (not just Oracle), result sets are non-deterministically ordered (unordered) unless you use an ORDER BY clause. Your data has no way of keeping the rows in that particular order so you cannot guarantee that the results will appear in that particular order. Assuming that you have a column that can be used to determine the order then:
From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   source
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY rn
         MEASURES
           FIRST(hbs1) AS hbs1,
           COUNT(*)    AS cnt
         PATTERN (same+)
         DEFINE same AS hbs1 = FIRST(hbs1)
       )

Or, in earlier versions you can use the ROW_NUMBER analytic function and then aggregate:
SELECT id,
       hbs1,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         hbs1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn)
           - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, hbs1 ORDER BY rn) AS grp
  FROM   source
)
GROUP BY id, hbs1, grp

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE source (ID, HBS1, rn) AS
SELECT 1, 'MU',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',   3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',   4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'T',   5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'T',   6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'SZ',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',   8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',   9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'S',  10 FROM DUAL;

Both output:



ID
HBS1
CNT




1
MU
1


1
S
3


1
T
2


1
SZ
1


1
S
3




If you are passing an already ordered result-set into the query and do not have a column that has a numbering then you can generate it using:
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT id, hbs1, ROWNUM AS rn FROM source)
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY rn
         MEASURES
           FIRST(hbs1) AS hbs1,
           COUNT(*)    AS cnt
         PATTERN (same+)
         DEFINE same AS hbs1 = FIRST(hbs1)
       )

fiddle
